# Windows Service throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException Works fine if enable "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-2.0, windows-server

We have 4 windows services which works on our servers alright however when installed them on the client's server 3 of them worked fine but one thrown following exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'myservice.core, Version=0.0.0.9999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'myservice.core, Version=0.0.0.9999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(Type hostType, String virtualDir, String physicalDir)
   at Advam.ParkBankServer.Listener.AppListener.OnStart(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

however if we go to properties of the service and select "Allow service to interact with desktop" above error goes away

[image]

But we really don't want it to run as interactive as we have a different code which runs when the application runs as interactive. This interactive code is for debugging and installation purposes only we can remove the code but that would require us to go through testing cycles anyway see the interact code below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log.Debug("Main. . ");
    if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        string parameter = string.Concat(args);

        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "--install":

                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;

            case "--uninstall":

                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;

            default:

                MyService service = new MyService();
                service.OnStart(args);
                Console.ReadKey();
                service.OnStop();
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() });
    }
}
```

By the way this dll is being used by other services as well but they are running fine however the only difference i can think of is that this service hosts some web-services in it and others don't. so is there anyway for us to fix it up without removal of the interactive code.

I didn't checked the version but probabaly it was "windows server 2008"

Comment: The "allow service to interact with desktop" option presumably results in the debugging code shown in your question being triggered.  That's an unnecessary complication, so you should take the debugging code away *temporarily* in order to troubleshoot your problem.  Once you've done that, please edit your question to describe what happens in that case.  I would guess that it will then fail even with "allow service to interact with desktop" being set.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I tested it and its working fine without the debugging code. it seem like something to do with some windows security setting.

Comment: Does it still work if "allow service to interact with desktop" isn't set?

Comment: I can imagine ways in which that setting could result in an "access denied" error, but a "file not found" error is hard to explain.  It might be worth using Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to see what is actually happening under the hood.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think that "File Not Found" is because of some permission issue and it could be due to some library is not being transparent about if file not there or its unable to read.  Anyway I have moved on to other things now. thanks for your feedback.